# Mode of Array C++

Tags: c++

My code to find the mode (most often) and how many times said mode was displayed runs into a never-ending loop. Does anyone know what I can do to fix it?

EDIT I UPDATED THE CODE: It returns 0, which is not the mode.

```
void calculateMode(int array[], int size)
{     
    int counter = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int mode = 0;
    for (int pass = 0; pass < size - 1; pass++)
        for (int count = pass + 1; count < size; count++) {
             if (array[count] > max) {
                max = array[count];
                mode = 1;
                counter = array[pass];
             }

             cout << "The mode is: " << counter "It's been displayed: " << count << "times" << endl; 

        }
```

Comment: `counter` is not the mode I think.

Comment: Your braces are not balanced.

Comment: `cout << "The mode is: " << counter << "It's been displayed: "`

Comment: How would I balance the braces?

Comment: your code doesn't compiler as-is btw due to the syntax error I mentioned and the unbalance brace by @Olaf.

Comment: for (int pass = 0; pass < size - 1; pass++){
        for (int count = pass + 1; count < size; count++) {
            if (array [count] == array [pass]){
                counter++;
            cout<< "The mode is: " << counter <<"It's been displayed: "<< count << "times" << endl;}//eno of if
               }//end of inner for
               }//end of outer for

Comment: I made that change, the loop terminates, but the mode is off.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to compute mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177647/algorithm-to-compute-mode)

Comment: To find the mode you need to compute how many times each separate character is found, and determine which of these numbers is the greatest. You are not doing that.

Comment: It's a list of numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920542/c-calculating-the-mode-of-a-sorted-array/19920685#19920685

Comment: The function returns `void`; it can't return anything else. You set `mode` to 0, and then maybe to 1, and then never use it. You report `"The mode is "<< counter` on *every iteration* through the inner loop. It's not at all clear what `max` represents, or why the inner loop is there at all. You also report `"It's been displayed: "<< count << "times"`, when `count` is just a loop counter, completely unrelated to the contents of the array. And you want to know why the code doesn't produce the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `map`. Compile with `g++ -std=c++11 a.cpp`.

Here is definition of [mode](http://www.mathsteacher.com.au/year8/ch17_stat/02_mean/mean.htm#mode)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3};
    map<int, int> count;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        count[v[i]]++;

    vector<int> mode;
    int cnt = 0;
    for (map<int, int>::iterator it = count.begin(); it != count.end(); ++it) {
        if (it->second > cnt) {
            mode.clear();
            mode.push_back(it->first);
            cnt = it->second;
        } else if (it->second == cnt) {
            mode.push_back(it->first);
        }
    }

    if (mode.size() * cnt == v.size()) {
        cout << "No mode" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "mode:";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < mode.size(); ++i)
            cout << ' ' << mode[i];
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The TS asks why his code doesn't work. This doesn't answer his question.

Comment: @n.m Yeah. I was aware of that.  I thought the OP doesn't actually understand what's the mode of an array.  So I think it will help to give him a simplified example to figure out what's wrong in his code.

Comment: @user2981720 I think your code doesn't actually compute mode.  Please refer to the definition of [mode](http://www.mathsteacher.com.au/year8/ch17_stat/02_mean/mean.htm#mode) and possible link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177647/algorithm-to-compute-mode?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This code uses "map" to find out the MODE from the given array. I hope this solution might help you.

```
int findMode(int * arr, int size)
{
    map<int, int> modeMap;
    sort(arr, arr + size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        ++modeMap[arr[i]];
    }

    auto x = std::max_element(modeMap.begin(), modeMap.end(),
        [](const pair<int, int>& a, const pair<int, int>& b) {
        return a.second < b.second; });

    return x->first;
}
```